# Detectar área de uma imagem no tempo certo (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

estou desenvolvendo um sistema para detecção de nível em garrafas ambar (Cerveja/Refrigerante), e estou com o seguinte problema:

**Sempre que a garrafa aparece na imagem o script já realiza a leitura mas com erros devido a garrafa não estar 100% na frente da webcam.**

Preciso detectar a área da imagem apenas quando a garrafa estiver inteira na frente da câmera.
Estou usando OpenCV e imutils, para fazer a tratativa da imagem.
Segue exemplo da má detecção:

[image: Falha na leitura]
[image: Falha na leitura]

O ideal seria a garrafa estar nessa posição para realizar a leitura:

[image: Leitura correta]

Vídeo de exemplo:

[image: Gif]

E para cada garrafa mal cheia eu estou chamando uma Thread para executar uma determinada função, o problema é que a Thread é chamada inúmeras vezes devido a cada frame que detectar mal-cheia, como faço para chamar apenas uma Thread para cada garrafa mal-cheia detectada ?

Segue partes do script:

```
    #Procura os contornos
contorno = cv2.findContours(garrafaEstrutura.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contorno = imutils.grab_contours(contorno)
#Classificar contornos
areas = [cv2.contourArea(contorno) for contorno in contorno]
if areas:
    (contorno, areas) = zip(*sorted(zip(contorno, areas), key=lambda a:a[1]))
    garrafaEstrutura = recortarImagem(frame.copy(), posicaox, posicaoy, largura, altura)
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contorno[-1])
    hh, ww, cc = garrafaEstrutura.shape
    valorParametro = int((ww + (hh/proporcao)) + (hh/proporcao))
    valorContorno = int((ww + y) + y)
    global tempoDistanciaAntecipada
    global tempoDistanciaPassada
    tempoDistanciaAntecipada = ww - (w+x)
    tempoDistanciaPassada = x
    #print("Distância antecipada:", tempoDistanciaAntecipada)
    #print("Distância Passada", tempoDistanciaPassada)
    #proporcaoGarrafa = w / float(h)
    #USAR O VALOR DO PARAMETRO X PARA DETECTAR A DISTANCIA QUE A CAMERA TIROU A FOTO
    if not modoTeste.get():
        if valorParametro > valorContorno:
            cv2.rectangle(garrafaEstrutura, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(garrafaEstrutura, "Cheia", (x + 10, y + 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        else:
            cv2.rectangle(garrafaEstrutura, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(garrafaEstrutura, "Mal-cheia", (x + 10, y + 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)     
            if not malcheiaUm:
                malUm = threading.Thread(name='threadMalcheiaUm', target=threadMalcheiaUm)
                if not malUm.is_alive():
                    try:
                        malUm.start()
                    except RuntimeError:
                        malUm = threading.Thread(name='threadMalcheiaUm', target=threadMalcheiaUm)
                        malUm.start()
```

Comment: separe essa imagem em parte superior e inferior, na superior vc deve fazer algumas condições para checar 3 estados, inicio meio fim, onde seram 0 ou 1: 000 seria sem garrafa(ou uma reset); 010 seria ponto de leitura de nivel

Comment: Algum pequeno esboço ?

Comment: não posso fazer codigos agora, na parte superior é para usar o pescoço para saber o momento onde tem ou não garrafa, seria como 3 sensores de presença mas usando a cor branca e o tom da garrafa na imagem, então na area inicial sendo branca, meio sendo escuro e fim sendo branca vc faria a leitura do nivel

Comment: Uma imagem com boa qualidade evita que sejam realizados tratamentos desnecessários na imagem. Sugiro colocar um "Backlight" e estudar um pouco dos conhecimentos básicos de fotografia e visão computacional industrial para realizar uma medição de nível. Outro ponto é a utilização de vídeos, em que você precisaria de um processamento desnecessário, utilize um sensor de trigger para obter as fotos no momento correto e sem o borrão do motion blur.